# How to autoload the first click of a button in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button created using the .xib file. I want the app to autoload the first question (meaning the ViewController to autoload the "showQuestion" method when the app first started. I am a beginner. How do you do it? Please help! Thanks!

ViewController.m

```
- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{

//call the init method implemented by the superclass
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
self.questions = @[@"What is your name?",
                   @"How old are you?",
                   @"Where are you from?"];
return self;
}
- (IBAction)showQuestion:(id)sender{
     self.questionLabel.text = self.questions[currentIndex];
}
```

the AppDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = vc;
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `-viewDidLoad` method of the view controller, just manually call the `-showQuestion` method.

i.e. in your ViewController.m, add this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self showQuestion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = vc;

// Autoload first question
[vc showQuestion:nil];

return YES;
}
```

ViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)showQuestion:(id)sender;
```